# how to check for existing cert with same common name - openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, pki

I’m trying to understand some code someone wrote as a wrapper for the openssl library / tool, with a view to updating it.

I'm completely new to openssl and PKI in general.  I found the following docs / references to help navigate but I wasn't able to find answer to my question.

http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~pcamacho/tutorial/crypto/openssl/openssl_intro.html

http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/

But I wasn't able to find the answer to my question.

**GOAL**

What I need to accomplish is to modify some code so that duplicate certs with the same common name and email addresses CANNOT be created if the cert is still active.
I am planning on checking the index.txt to see if a cert with the same common name exists, and if it hasn't been revoked, I'll prevent user from creating it again.

**Problem:**

When I create a certificate using this webtool, I see that the index.txt file in /etc/ssl/ is updated with a record starting with a "V". 
When I revoke a certificated, the V is changed to R.
However, when I delete a certificate, nothing is updated in the index.txt file. The record remains the same -it's not updated with a new status, nor is it deleted from the file.

**QUESTIONS**

Is it a bug that the openssl index.txt file is not updated when a cert is deleted?
If it is, what is the command to update the index.txt to remove a cert?
Maybe the wrapper is where the problem is ... the developer may have just forgotten to run a command line tool to update in index.txt file?  I guess I just don't know how openssl is supposed to handle a cert deletion and therefore, i can't tell if i have a bug or not... and who's bug it is.

Is there a way using the openssl toolset to check for duplicate certs so that I don't have to manually check index.txt?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a certificate is not an operation a CA would typically implement.  To make a certificate invalid before the validity period ends, it is revoked.  But they are not normally deleted, since a CA would want to track which certificates it has issued.  So I am not sure why you are looking into deleting certificates.

However, you seem to be using `openssl ca` with the example CA scripts bundled with OpenSSL.  Depending on your exact needs, you might be looking for the `unique_subject` [configuration file option](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ca.html) which enforces that only a single valid certificate for any subject can exist at the same time.

Comment: if i change this from no to yes, do i have to do anything else to "reset" it?

Comment: i've modified the config file to have "yes" for the unique subject but it's still allowing me to create duplicate certifictes...